# Higher Order Derivatives

Tags: python, derivative

I am trying to write a python program in which the user inputs the polynomial and it calculates the derivative. My current code is:

```
print ("Derviatives: ")
k5 = raw.input("Enter 5th degree + coefficent:     ")
k4 = raw.input("Enter 4th degree + coefficent:     ")
k3 = raw.input("Enter 3rd degree + coefficent:     ")
k2 = raw.input("Enter 2nd degree + coefficent:     ")
k1 = raw.input("Enter 1st degree + coefficent:     ")
k0 = raw.input("Enter constant:    ")
int(k5)
int(k4)
int(k3)
int(k2)
int(k1)
int(k0)
print (k5, "  ", k4, "  ", k3, "  ", k2, "   ", k1, "  ", k0)
1in =  raw.input("Correct Y/N?")
if (1in != Y)
    k5 = raw.input("Enter 5th degree + coefficent:     ")
    k4 = raw.input("Enter 4th degree + coefficent:     ")
    k3 = raw.input("Enter 3rd degree + coefficent:     ")
    k2 = raw.input("Enter 2nd degree + coefficent:     ")
    k1 = raw.input("Enter 1st degree + coefficent:     ")
    k0 = raw.input("Enter constant:    ")   

else
    """CODE GOES HERE"""
```

I am just a beginning python programmer so I am still a little bit fuzzy on some basic syntax issues.  Are there any libraries that I should be importing?

Comment: I think spending time carefully working through a language tutorial would be a good investment. While you are at it, I'd recommend reading up on the `list` data type.

Comment: As to answer your actual question: no, there aren't any libraries you need (for now; perhaps once your program extends you may need them). But there are lots of grammatical (syntax) errors. Start smaller, and try to run the program each time you add something to it.

Comment: You have syntax errors, and you badly need to learn how to loop and use lists, but what you have so far doesn't need any additional imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Sympy:

Put these two lines at the top:

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
```

And these at the part """CODE GOES HERE"""

```
x = Symbol('x')
y = k5*x**5  + k4*x**4 + k3*x**3  + k2*x**2  + k1*x  +constant
yprime = y.diff(x)
yprime
```

Comment: I assume it's a sort of homework, he's doing, so he's supposed to implement the algorithm manually, without just calling readily available libraries.

Answer (score 1):

OK, use `raw_input` instead of `raw.input`. It is builtin, as is `int`, so nothing needs importing. When converting to a integer (`int`), you need to assign the result, or nothing will change. You can chain the functions, and use `k5 = int(raw_input("prompt.. "))`. Also, as pointed out by Evert, variable names cannot begin with numbers, so `1in` would have to be changed. This code should work:

```
print("Derviatives: ")
k5 = raw_input("Enter 5th degree + coefficent:     ")
k4 = raw_input("Enter 4th degree + coefficent:     ")
k3 = raw_input("Enter 3rd degree + coefficent:     ")
k2 = raw_input("Enter 2nd degree + coefficent:     ")
k1 = raw_input("Enter 1st degree + coefficent:     ")
k0 = raw_input("Enter constant:    ")
k5 = int(k5)
k4 = int(k4)
k3 = int(k3)
k2 = int(k2)
k1 = int(k1)
k0 = int(k0)
print(k5, "  ", k4, "  ", k3, "  ", k2, "   ", k1, "  ", k0)
in1 = raw_input("Correct Y/N?")
if in1 != "Y":
    k5 = raw_input("Enter 5th degree + coefficent:     ")
    k4 = raw_input("Enter 4th degree + coefficent:     ")
    k3 = raw_input("Enter 3rd degree + coefficent:     ")
    k2 = raw_input("Enter 2nd degree + coefficent:     ")
    k1 = raw_input("Enter 1st degree + coefficent:     ")
    k0 = raw_input("Enter constant:    ")   

else:
    """CODE GOES HERE"""
```

Also, check which version of python you are using. If it is python 3, you need to change `raw_input` to `input`. If you are using python 2, you don't need the brackets on the print statements. E.g. `print("Derviatives: ")` => `print "Derviatives: "`.

Comment: This code won't work either: `1in` is not a valid variable.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following issues with your code:

1. Variable names can't start with a digit: `1in`
2. You have undefined variable `Y`. I suppose you want to compare with a string literal, so write `"Y"` instead.
3. Parentheses aren't needed in python's `if` operators, but a trailing colon is necessary. Same goes for `else`.
4. A list of coefficients would be certainly a better approach than a bunch of variables.
5. It's `raw_input`, not `raw.input`
6. While just doing `int(k5)` would validate the value (raise the exception if string doesn't represent an integer) it won't affect variable, so `k5` would still contain a string.

Guess it wouldn't hurt to show a bit of code, since I'm not doing your task here (implementing the algorithm), but merely displaying language features. So... I'd do it somehow like this:

```
# There are no do...while-style loops in Python, so we'll do it this way
# loop forever, and break when confirmation prompt gets "y"
while True:
    k = []  # That's an empty list.

    # I'm assuming Python 2.x here. Add parentheses for Python 3.x.
    print "Derivatives:"

    # This range will work like a list [5, 4, 3, 2, 1].
    for n in range(5, 1, -1):
        k.append(int(raw_input("Enter {0}th degree + coefficient:  ".format(n)))

    ## Or you could do it this way:
    #for num in ["5th", "4th", "3rd", "2nd", "1st"]:
    #    k.append(int(raw_input("Enter {0} degree + coefficient:  ".format(num)))

    k.append(int(raw_input("Enter constant:  ".format(n)))

    # Here's a bit tricky part - a list comprehension.
    # Read on those, they're useful.
    # We need the comprehension, because our list is full of ints,
    # and join experts a list of strings.
    print " ".join(str(x) for x in k)

    ## If you didn't get the previous line - that's fine,
    ## it's fairly advanced subject. Just do like you're used to:
    #print k[0], " ", k[1], " ", k[2], " ", k[3], " ", k[4], " ", k[5]

    # Oh, and did you notice 5th coeff. is at k[0]?
    # That's because we appended them to the list in reverse order.
    # Let's reverse the list in-place, so the constant will be k[0] and so on.
    k.reverse()

    # You don't always need an intermediate variable for single-use values,
    # like when asking for confirmation. Just put raw_input call directly
    # in if statement condition - it would work just fine.
    #
    # And let's be case-insensitive here and accept both "Y" and "y"
    if raw_input("Correct [Y/N]? ").lower() == "y":
        break
```

Comment: But how do I do the limit involved in the f'(x)?